# Check if value exist in mongo collection

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm working in node js  and I'm using mongo (Im absolute beginner) . Now I need to have collection that basically needs to look like this array

`var keys = ['key1','key2','key3']` // with this I easily can check if some value I have exist in this array with indexOf function ,

Now I need to make collection in mongo that only needs to store keys that user makes and if key already exist in collection it need to do nothing.

//My keys looks something like this , it can be one string or it can be an array of string

```
Keys = 'home4.car3' or Keys = ['home4.car3','home2.car4']
```

// I'm doing insert like this

```
db.collection('keys',function(err, collection){
            collection.insert(Keys, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
                } else {
                    console.log("success");
                }
            });
        });
```

NOW Here is what happened when I first insert array of two keys into db , and then after that one string :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fc7730e398519cffde3f

Does anyone can tell me how to to insert for this and how to filter those keys to check if they are into collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you're storing your documents like an array, why don't you just store them as an array? If you come from a relational database background, I can see how you'd be tempted to store it that way, but in Mongo, if it's like an array, it should just be stored as an array.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e5361f30f28b6b602e4c7f"),
    "0" : "h",
    "1" : "o",
    "2" : "m"
}
```

Should be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e5361f30f28b6b602e4c7f"),
    "keys" : [ "h", "o", "m" ]
}
```

In this case, Mongo has a handy operator called `$addToSet` that will work just like `$push` except that it will only add it to the array if it doesn't exist. The operation would look something like this:

```
collection.update( query, { $addToSet : { 'keys' : 'l' }}, callback );
// add key 'l'

collection.update( query, { $addToSet : { 'keys' : 'm' }}, callback );
// looks in document, sees 'm' in array, and does nothing
```

EDIT:

With the update, it will add the key to the array if it's not there, but if you ONLY want to know if it exists or not, I think the best way would be to use `findOne`:

```
// find the doc by _id  and the value you want in keys, returns null if it's not a match
collection.findOne({ _id : 52e5361f30f28b6b602e4c7f, 'keys' : 'l' }, function(err, doc) {
    if( doc == null ) {
        // do whatever you need to do if it's not there
    } else {
        // do whatever you need to if it is there
    }
    db.close();
}
```

To keep your insert as is, you would just need to change `Keys` to:

```
Keys = { 'keys' : [ 'key1', 'key2', 'key3' ] };
```

And the insert shouldn't need to change otherwise. Also, in your collection, you might want to change the `_id` to be `username` or add a `username` field to your document.

Comment: how to get event if its not in array because i need to trigger function on that event ? And can you show me how insert would look like now

Comment: No problem! If your question was successfully answered, please accept the answer.