# Most efficient way to check if element exists in a set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

so in my MongoDB database I have a collection holding user posts.

Within that collection I have a set called "likes", which holds an array of the ids of the users that have liked that post. When querying I would like to pass a user id to my query and have a boolean in the result telling me whether the id exists in the array to see whether the user has already liked the post. I understand this would be easy to do with two queries, one to get the post and one to check if the user has liked it, but I would like to find the most efficient way to do this.

For example, one of my documents looks like this

```
{
    _id: 24jef247jos991,
    post: "Test Post",
    likes: ["userid1", "userid2"]
}
```

When I query from "userid1" I would like the return

```
{
    _id: 24jef247jos991,
    post: "Test Post",
    likes: ["userid1", "userid2"],
    userLiked: true
}
```

But when I query from let's say "userid3" I would like

```
{
    _id: 24jef247jos991,
    post: "Test Post",
    likes: ["userid1", "userid2"],
    userLiked: false
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if value exist in mongo collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366814/check-if-value-exist-in-mongo-collection)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question asks something different. I understand how to not add duplicates to a collection and how to use addToSet to do that operation. This is more of a question asking how to mix the result of two queries into one.

Comment: did you look at the edit at the bottom of the accepted answer ?

Comment: @Veeram Yes, which suggests you use the findOne operator. My question is how to do this with one query such as an aggregate query. Using findOne would generate one extra query for every post in the results.

Comment: Okay. Unlinked. Thanks for adding details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `$addFields` stage checking each of the document `likes` arrays against the input user.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
        {
           $addFields: {
              "userLiked":{ $in: [ "userid1", "$likes" ] }
           }
        }
] )
```

Comment: Actually I had to use the $in operator instead of $eq for some reason, but the general idea works.

Comment: That is indeed correct. Updated answer. $eq aggregation operator works little bit different from $eq query operator. $in operator support in project / addFields stage was only added recently  from 3.3.5 version. Thank you for verifying. Here is the relevant ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6146

Answer (score 1):

Starting from MongoDB 3.4 you can use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator to check if an array contains a given element. You can use the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) operator aggregation operator to add the newly computed value to your document without explicitly including other fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
   { "$addFields": { "userLiked": { "$in": [ "userid1", "$likes" ] } } }
])
```

In MongoDB 3.2, you can use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset) operator and the square bracket `[]` operator to do this. The downside of this approach is that you need to manually [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) all the field in your document. Also the `$setIsSubset` operator with de-duplicate your array which may not be what you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "post": 1, "likes": 1, 
        "userLiked": { "$setIsSubset": [ [ "userid3" ], "$likes" ] } 
    }}
])
```

Finally if your `mongod` version is 3.0 or older you need to use the `$literal` operator instead of the `[]` operator.

Comment: Thanks, my production database is actually mongo 3.2, I ended up solving this by filtering the array and then getting it's size and checking if the size was > 1, but this is probably more efficient

Comment: Also note that the answer you accepted is wrong because the first expression in the the `$in` operator should be the input value. I don't know how your are using the newly computed field, but you can combine `$filter` with `$redact` but keep in mind that `$redact` does a collscan

Comment: @M.StyvaneSoukossi  Thank you for commenting on my answer. Fixed the order of expressions.